# How can I select n items and skip m from ndarray in python?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

Let's say I have an ndarray with 100 elements, and I want to select the first 4 elements, skip 6 and go ahead like this (in other words, select the first 4 elements every 10 elements).

I tried with python slicing with step but I think it's not working in my case. How can I do that? I'm using Pandas and numpy, can they help? I searched around but I have found nothing like that kind of slicing. Thanks!

Comment: Shape of the input ndarray? Along which axis do you want to do this selection?

Comment: My ndarray X has shape (100,1) because I reshaped it in order to use these points along with y ndarray to plot a diagram with pyplot. But I want to plot just the first 4 elements every 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`NumPy slicing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to solve your case.

For a `1D` array case -

```
A.reshape(-1,10)[:,:4].reshape(-1)
```

This can be extended to a `2D` array case with the selection to be made along the first axis -

```
A.reshape(-1,10,A.shape[1])[:,:4].reshape(-1,A.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reshape the array to a `10x10`, then use slicing to pick the first 4 elements of each row. Then flatten the reshaped, sliced array:

```
In [46]: print a
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74
 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]

In [47]: print a.reshape((10,-1))[:,:4].flatten()
[ 0  1  2  3 10 11 12 13 20 21 22 23 30 31 32 33 40 41 42 43 50 51 52 53 60
 61 62 63 70 71 72 73 80 81 82 83 90 91 92 93]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `% 10`:

```
print [i for i in range(100) if i % 10 in (0, 1, 2, 3)]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 31, 32, 33, 40, 41, 42, 43, 50, 51, 52, 53, 60, 61, 62, 63, 70, 71, 72, 73, 80, 81, 82, 83, 90, 91, 92, 93]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
shorter_arr = arr[np.arange(len(arr))%10 < 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example in OP, the input array is divisible by `m+n`. If it's not, then you could use the below function `take_n_skip_m`. It expands on @Divakar's answer by padding the input array to make it reshapeable into a proper 2D matrix; slice, flatten and slice again to get the desired outcome:

```
def take_n_skip_m(arr, n=4, m=6):
    # in case len(arr) is not divisible by (n+m), get the remainder
    remainder = len(arr) % (n+m)
    # will pad arr with (n+m-remainder) 0s at the back
    pad_size = (0, n+m-remainder)
    # pad arr; reshape to create 2D array; take first n of each row; flatten 2D->1D
    sliced_arr = np.pad(arr, pad_size).reshape(-1, n+m)[:, :n].flatten()
    # remove any remaining padding constant if there is any (which depends on whether remainder >= n or not)
    return sliced_arr if remainder >= n else sliced_arr[:remainder-n]
```

Examples:

```
>>> out = take_n_skip_m(np.arange(20), n=5, m=4)
>>> print(out)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  9 10 11 12 13 18 19]

>>> out = take_n_skip_m(np.arange(20), n=5, m=6)
>>> print(out)
[ 0  1  2  3  4 11 12 13 14 15]
```